# Sonata Media PNG compression with alpha channel

Tags: symfony, png, gd, sonata-media-bundle

SonataMediaBundle increases PNG image size with this settings:

```
video_image:
    providers:
        - sonata.media.provider.image
    formats:
        medium: { width: 1306, quality: 100 }
```

Original image size is 246Kb (with same width and height), and the size of the "resized" image is 3Mb. It happens because of `quality: 100` that sets `png_compression_level => 0`.

If I set `quality: 0`, PNG size is almost ok (and image looks very ok), but JPG compression makes image look like impressionism.

So I solved it with a custom resizer for PNG images.

But with setting `png_compression_level => 9` the size of compressed image  is still not ideal, it's 664Kb.

Converting PNG image to PNG8 solved this, and the size became very ok - 233Kb (that is even smaller than the original image), but I got some troubles with the alpha channel.

Most of images with transparency compressed fine, but some of them were corrupted:

original image (it is white on transparent bg)

> [image: a white border]

compressed image

> [image: the same but smaller]

This is my custom resizer (the code is a little bit ugly, because it's just a draft):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Resizer;

use Gaufrette\File;
use Imagine\Gd\Image;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Resizer\SimpleResizer;

class PngCustomResizer extends SimpleResizer
{
    public function resize(MediaInterface $media, File $in, File $out, $format, array $settings)
    {
        /** @var Image $image */
        $image = $this->adapter->load($in->getContent());

        $thumbnail = $image->thumbnail($this->getBox($media, $settings), $this->mode);

        $resource = $thumbnail->getGdResource();

        $width = $thumbnail->getSize()->getWidth();
        $height = $thumbnail->getSize()->getHeight();

        // convert to png8 with alpha
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $bga = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagecolortransparent($img, $bga);
        imagefill($img, 0, 0, $bga);
        imagecopy($img, $resource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
        imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 255);
        imagealphablending($img, false);
        imagesavealpha($img, true);

        $optimizedImage = new Image($img, $image->palette(), $image->metadata());

        // set quality 0 to set png compression = 9
        $content = $optimizedImage->get($format, ['quality' => 0]);

        $out->setContent($content, $this->metadata->get($media, $out->getName()));
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or may be I should use another way?

All I want is resize both JPG and PNG files without increasing size and without noticeable loss of quality.

**UPDATE**

1. `imagetruecolortopalette` resets alpha values to 0 or 127, without 2-126 values. So image's edges loose their smoothness. I'm trying to fix it setting old alpha value for each pixel, but don't have success yet
2. artefacts on the above-mentioned image appear just in small size resizing ('thumb' in this config)

   ```
   formats:
       wide: { width: 1306, quality: 95}
       mobile: { width: 640, quality: 95}
       thumb: { height: 50 , quality: 95}
   ```

so I presume that the trouble is in compounding some not-fully-transparent pixels

Comment: The transparency hides it, but it seems there is some data in those pixels after all. If you blank out all channels with a fully transparent alpha, those downsample artefacts should disappear. You (probably) could adjust your code to do that, or use an external tool.

Comment: could you please clarify what do you mean here "If you blank out all channels with a fully transparent alpha"? not sure I understand it well

Comment: See this discussion on the ImageMagick forum: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13746 and this (also ImageMagick) overview: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_compress. From there: "PNG image will preserve the color of fully-transparent pixels. That is even though you can not see it transparency has color, and PNG preserves that data."

Answer (score 1):

I tried different ways with GD functions, but did not get satisfactory result.

So the best way I found is to use Imagick instead of GD:

services.yml:

```
    sonata.media.resizer.custom:
        class: AppBundle\Resizer\CustomResizer
        arguments: [@sonata.media.adapter.image.imagick, 'outbound', @sonata.media.metadata.proxy]
```

AppBundle\Resizer\CustomResizer:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Resizer;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Resizer\SimpleResizer;

class PngCustomResizer extends SimpleResizer
{
}
```

config.yml:

```
sonata_media:
    providers:
        image:
            resizer: sonata.media.resizer.custom
```